# Confirm if an IP is in a list of CIDR

Tags: awk, sed, scripting, ip

Given an IPv4 address, is it possible to verify if the IP is in the range of a list of CIDR?

For example, if I have the following CIDR, is there any way to check if `100.31.255.4` is in the range of any of the CIDR?

```
100.16.0.0/12
100.46.0.0/12
100.100.0.0/24
100.100.5.0/22
```

Preferably done using bultin Mac/BSD tools.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9):

Using [`grepcidr`](http://www.pc-tools.net/unix/grepcidr/) with the list of net blocks in `list`:

```
$ echo '100.31.255.4' | grepcidr -f list
100.31.255.4

$ echo '10.31.255.4' | grepcidr -f list
(no output)
```

As a test:

```
if printf '%s\n' "$ipaddr" | grepcidr -f list >/dev/null; then
    printf '%s is in the list\n' "$ipaddr"
else
    printf '%s is not in the list\n' "$ipaddr"
fi
```