# grep for an IP range?

Tags: grep, terminal, rhel, ip, subnets

On a RHEL 7 box whose local IP address is 10.0.0.159, the following command prints out the IP `10.0.0.159`:

```
$ echo "$(ifconfig eth0 | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | \
   grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1')""(rw,sync)"
```

What would the command have to change to in order to print out `10.0.0.0/8" instead?

Comment: Consider the `ipcalc` command; the Debian version outputs a Network line that may be useful.

Comment: Very related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448762/confirm-if-an-ip-is-in-a-list-of-cidr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE:** `ifconfig` is a deprecated cmd. your should be using cmds. in the iproute2 package going forward. Below I show how to use `ip` to accomplish what you want using the replacement tool.

---

Rather than do this with `ifconfig` I'd recommend using the `ip` command instead.

#### IP CIDR

This form shows the IP address in CIDR notation:

```
$ ip addr list eth0 | awk '/inet.*brd/ {print $2}'
10.0.2.15/24

-or-

$ ip a l eth0 | awk '/inet.*brd/ {print $2}'
10.0.2.15/24
```

#### Network CIDR

This form shows the network address in CIDR notation:

```
$ ip route show | awk '/eth0.*scope/ {print $1}'
10.0.2.0/24
```

#### ipcalc

You can also use the `ipcalc` command to manipulate the above addresses to calculate other formats. For example:

```
$ ipcalc -n $(ip a l eth0 | awk '/inet.*brd/ {print $2}')
NETWORK=10.0.2.0

$ ipcalc -p $(ip a l eth0 | awk '/inet.*brd/ {print $2}')
PREFIX=24
```

With `ipcalc` you can use it to more simply form whatever variations you want, rather than have to do a lot of `sed` & `awk` to parse text that's typically overly complicated to do.

Answer (score 3):

To change a command line to do what you want, first you need to understand what it is doing. Here's an analysis:

```
echo "$(<something>)""(rw,sync)"
```

Will run `something` and take it as input to your `echo`. Everything else is normal text to be `echo`'ed.

```
ifconfig eth0
```

Gets the network information.

```
grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*'
```

Isolates the several IPs in your system. `-E` tells grep to use regular expressions, which is why you can use `[0-9]*` to match all numbers together, for example. `-o` tells grep to output only the part that matches the regular expression, as opposed to outputting the whole line that matches the grep condition, as it would by default. So if for example the input line is `inet addr:10.0.0.159  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0`, it will only output `inet addr:10.0.0.159` leaving out the `Bcast` and `Mask` parts.

```
grep -Eo  '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*'
```

This is exactly the same as above, except without the label `inet addr`, meaning you're isolating specifically the IP and removing the label. And finally,

```
grep -v '127.0.0.1'
```

is removing that one IP from your list of outputs, because you don't care about the loopback IP.

---

As you can see, your command is getting the output of `ifconfig` and filtering information out, isolating only the piece of information that you want. It's not doing any calculations or information processing. But what you want it to print is the subnet and mask, which are information that are not explicitly displayed by `ifconfig`. In other words you can't just filter things out differently to get what you want. You will have to do some processing, some calculation using the `Mask` field at the end of the line. In summary, you can't "change the command to print out what you want". You have to create a completely different command.

slm's answer uses a similar technique (filtering out information to keep only what you want), but changed the input to a command that will have the information that you need. :-) If you didn't have a command that outputs exactly what you want, and doing some processing on it was your only option, here's an ugly set of `if`s that you can use as an example or base in the future. It uses slm's first solution, and it assumes your mask is always 8, 16 or 24.

```
ip a l eth1 | awk '/inet.*brd/ {split($2,add,"/");split(add[1],ip,".");if(add[2]<=24){ip[4]=0} if(add[2]<=16){ip[3]=0} if(add[2]<=8){ip[2]=0} print ip[1]"."ip[2]"."ip[3]"."ip[4]"/"add[2];}'
```

This command split the output of `ip` between `add`ress (10.0.0.159) and mask (8). Then it splits the IP into its 4 numbers. Then it sets the numbers to zero according to the mask. But it's not bitwise, meaning it will only deal with masks 8, 16 and 24, because that's what I hardcoded. ;)

I hope you could learn a bit more about the tools at your hand. ^_^

Comment: ifconfig is a deprecated cmd. We should be enlightening ppl to the migration to iproute2 cmds. RHEL7 would be one of the OSes where iproute2 is on by default.

Comment: my goal was to enlighten OP on more basic things, like grep. ;)

Comment: Fair point 8-)   !